# IE10 and after pseudoelements

Tags: html, css, hover, internet-explorer-10

I'm doing a very simple transition on a h3 hover with an after pseudoelement. I've read that ::after works on IE10 (and it does as it renders it), but not the hover.

```css
h3 {
  position:relative;
}
h3::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
h3:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
h3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h3>
<a href='#'>Hello</a>
</h3>
```

Other browsers works as a charm, I don't know what happens with IE10...

Comment: ie10 emulation works for me.

Comment: @Huelfe It works for you? I tried this exact same code in a IE10, and doesn't works. I don't know why, but if I try with an `<a>` instead of a `<h3>` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding empty hover selector for h3.
h3:hover {}

Comment: Looks it works. In a JSFiddle, it works fine with that, but for a reason I can't understand, the same exact code in my project, it doesn't.

Comment: OK, it was something related to some javascript the project had before we got it, and some "if's" for IE, but that thing you provided worked like a charm too, thanks!